# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/does-communism-restrict-freedom) was closed, and even though I have edited it, it still doesn't seem to be eligible for opening.  Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I still consider the question subjective and argumentative, you're asking about a topic where people have strong opinions, you quote an extremely inflammatory opinion about that topic, and "slaves" is also not exactly a neutral term. Even restated in neutral terms, I would consider it "not a real question", your terms are not well defined, it is not clear what you are really asking about.

If you can convince 5 people with >500 repuation to open it, fine. I won't use my supervote as moderator to reopen that question.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not the right place for questions of this nature. That does not mean that it isn't a good question, but just that it isn't the type of question that we can help with here. There really isn't a a claim made here that can be verified, so it is off-topic. Also, the nature of the question is subjective. Ask 100 people, and you are likely to get 101 answers. It is too opinion based. Most political and legal questions are like this.

Please do not take this as an insult, as it is not intended that way. We just have to stay within our narrow scope of support or die by scope creep.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the rep to vote for a reopen. You need [500 rep.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions)

You will also need at least [250 rep](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes) to see when actions like this one are taken.

Comment: i want to know why is it still closed.

Comment: @alaukik, you asked why it does not seem to be eligible for reopening, you cannot tell if people are voting to reopen it. It takes 5 people with >500 rep considering it worth reopening. you can flag for moderator attention and ask them if they will reopen it. They will be significantly harder to convince then 5 random users, but getting 5 users to start reopen vote normally takes work also, or a great edit with a lot of publicity.

Answer (score 0):

As of my writing this, there are no re-open votes.

A good question for here has a claim that can be objectively tested.  It doesn't ask for a list of pros or cons.  It asks one question that is amenable to an objective answer.

This question asked for pros and cons, and concluded with an inflammatory question that looks more rhetorical than actual to me.